# Splitting comma separated email addresses in a string with commas in quotes

Tags: php, split

Say I have the following email addresses comma separated in a string:

```
$addrList = 'Kevin.Brine@pppg.com, Robert.Thomas@pppg.com, "Guice, Doug" <Doug.Guice@pppg.com>';
```

I need the following result:

```
[0] => Kevin.Brine@pppg.com
[1] => Robert.Thomas@pppg.com
[2] => "Guice, Doug" <Doug.Guice@pppg.com>
```

Seems fairly simple, but that comma in the quoted name really has thrown me in trying to find a solution using either preg_match_all or preg_split. Also we should accommodate for emails that use single quotes for names too, ie: `'smith, tom' <tom.smith@abc.com>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[str_getcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) should give you what you need, though it will strip the quotes.

**EDIT**

If you want to put the quotes back in:

```
$addrList = 'Kevin.Brine@pppg.com, Robert.Thomas@pppg.com, "Guice, Doug" <Doug.Guice@pppg.com>';


$t = str_getcsv($addrList);

foreach($t as $k => $v) {
    if (strpos($v,',') !== false) {
        $t[$k] = '"'.str_replace(' <','" <',$v);
    }
}

var_dump($t);
```

Comment: Great idea -- I just tried it, and I'm losing the actual email address on the last entry in the string -- I only get the name: Guice, Doug.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You're echoing it to a web browser aren't you! How does a browser react when it sees <anything> ? Try doing var_dump() instead

Comment: OH you are soo good.  I totally missed that!  Thanks so much!!

Comment: I normally work in Zend Studio 5.5 (which is only php 5.1 I think) -- but since str_getcsv() is php 5.3+, I just ran it off my server & browser (just as you said!) and totally forgot about the tag effect!  Thanks again!